# ForEach File enumerator: UNC path doesn't work - even locally

Tags: file, ssis

Versions: VS 2019, VSTA 2019 - target server version 2012.

I'm setting up a very simple ForEach File enumerator in a new package.

I'm already fully aware of the gotchas that happen when you move from running locally in VS to deploying to an SSIS server, and then running the pkg (possibly) under a completely different user account (e.g. SQL Agent).  Please note this question is **not** about that: this is running locally in VS.

So, to forestall these gotchas on deployment, I used an UNC folder path.  No good.  No loops in the enumerator; *Progress* windows shows "Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty."

Did I spell something wrong, bad file filter, forgot to put a \ on the end?  Nope, that makes no difference.

2. Tried with a local C:\Temp... path.  Works fine.
3. Tried *exactly the same location* as specified by the UNC path, but using my (local) mapped network drive instead of an UNC at the start.  Works fine.

Of course, this mapped drive letter will probably not exist on the deployment server - which is exactly why I used an UNC to start with.

Can I conclude that the ForEach File enumerator is just broken if you use it with UNCs?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make that conclusion. Foreach File enumerator and UNCs work just fine.

### Set up

On my computer, ERECH, I open a command prompt as administrator and ran the following commands. It creates a new folder so_73155152 at C:\ssisdata\input, creates 3 files with .txt extensions in that folder and then shared the folder. `net share` allows me to create a share and `net view` allows me to see what shares are available on a server for the current user.

```
C:\ssisdata\so\input>mkdir so_73155152

C:\ssisdata\so\input>cd so_73155152

C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152>echo > file1.txt

C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152>echo > file2.txt

C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152>echo > file3.txt

C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152> net share so_73155152=C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152

C:\ssisdata\so\input>net view erech
Shared resources at erech



Share name                             Type   Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brother HL-L2340D series (2019-04-14)  Print           Brother HL-L2340D series (2019-04-14)
DEV2017                                Disk            SQL Server FILESTREAM share
so_73155152                            Disk
```

At this point, we should be able to enumerate either the unc path `\\erech\so_73155152` or `C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152`

### Repo package

2 global variables: `LocalPath` & `UncPath` populated with the above values.
I then created a Sequence container which has 2 variables scoped within it: `CurrentFile` & `SourcePath` (By default, variables are now created at the global scope so you will need to click the Move Variable button in the Variable window)

Inside the Sequence Container, I added a Foreach File Enumerator. I configured it to set an expression on the `Directory` for `@[User::SourcePath]`. In Variable Mappings, I assign `@[User::CurrentFile]` to element 0.

Inside the Foreach, I have a Script task set up to [emit the current value of variables](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html).

I specify the following variables `System::TaskName,User::CurrentFile,User::SourcePath`

The code itself is

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_233af211b9664d3d849319c513083aca
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            string template = "{0}->{1}";
            bool fireAgain = false;
            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo back", string.Format(template, item.QualifiedName, item.Value.ToString()), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

The point of this pattern is to allow the same set of Tasks to run using different initial values. Copy paste the sequence container and then configure the individual containers to have an Expression on SourcePath to either the UncPath or the LocalPath variable.

For clarity in the output, I renamed the Script Tasks to align with the scenario I was testing.

[image]

### Results

```
"C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\SO_73155152.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: User::CurrentFile->\\erech\so_73155152\file1.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: User::SourcePath->\\erech\so_73155152
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: System::TaskName->SCR Echo UNC
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: User::CurrentFile->\\erech\so_73155152\file2.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: User::SourcePath->\\erech\so_73155152
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: System::TaskName->SCR Echo UNC
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: User::CurrentFile->\\erech\so_73155152\file3.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: User::SourcePath->\\erech\so_73155152
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo UNC, SCR Echo back: System::TaskName->SCR Echo UNC
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: User::CurrentFile->C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152\file1.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: User::SourcePath->C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: System::TaskName->SCR Echo Local
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: User::CurrentFile->C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152\file2.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: User::SourcePath->C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: System::TaskName->SCR Echo Local
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: User::CurrentFile->C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152\file3.txt
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: User::SourcePath->C:\ssisdata\so\input\so_73155152
Information: 0x0 at SCR Echo Local, SCR Echo back: System::TaskName->SCR Echo Local
SSIS package "C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash\SO_73155152.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

From the Output tab, you can see the above activity. Were I to change the value of my UncPath to `\\NoRealComputer\so_73155152` I will see the following output

> Warning: 0x8001C004 at FELC List Files: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.

If I were to change the UncPath to `\\ERECH\so_73155152X` I would see the same warning.

If I were to deny access to the share to myself, I will generate that same warning.

The way I would diagnose error with unc vs permissions is back to the command line.

With my revoked permissions, I would see the following when I attempt to list the directory.

```
C:\ssisdata\so\input>dir \\erech\so_73155152
Access is denied.
```

NET VIEW will still list the share as visible, but I have no permissions to work within the share.

Whereas a mangled path will result in a network name cannot be found

```
C:\ssisdata\so\input>dir \\erech\so_73155152
The network name cannot be found.

C:\ssisdata\so\input>dir \\erech2\so_73155152x
The network name cannot be found.
```